# Converting columns into rows in a collection using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, vb.net-2010

I need to convert the following columns into rows using linq

```
Id  Numb1 Numb2 Numb3
100 1   2   3
200 10  20  30
```

into

```
 Id Numbers     Code
100 1   A
100 2   D
100 3   R
200 10  E
200 20  T
200 30  H
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you're okay hard-coding which columns will get pivoted.  For each item you select its numbers and flatten the resulting list.  This query gets translated to a [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) statement.

```
From item in items _
From number in { item.Numb1, item.Numb2, item.Numb3 } _
Select New Class2 With { .Id = item.Id, .Number = number }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy..that worked..One more question..The query returns both Id and number in same index like query(0) =Id,number. Do i need to split it manually and store in my attributes, or any better way there? I cant do a loop with generic list, since it is in my custom collection

Comment: @user1762476: Do you mean you want to select an instance of a class instead of an anonymous object?  If so, see my update.